# Resolving spark dependencies using sbt

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, dependencies, sbt

I was trying to build a very basic scala script having spark dependencies .
But I am not able to make the jar out of it .

The error generated :

> sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;1.6.0-SNAPSHOT: not found

My build.sbt :

```
    import Dependencies._

    lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
     settings(
               inThisBuild(List(
                                 organization := "com.example",
                                 scalaVersion := "2.12.1",
                                 version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
                              )),
               name := "Hello",
               libraryDependencies +=  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0-SNAPSHOT",
               resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
                )
```

`

```
package example
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object Hello  {
     def main(args: Array[String]) {
           val logFile = "/Users/dhruvsha/Applications/spark/README.md"                 
           val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
           val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
           val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
           val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
           val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
           println(s"Lines with a: $numAs, Lines with b: $numBs")
           sc.stop()
         }
}
```

My source scala is in :

> /exampleapp/main/scala/example/Hello.scala

Project name is exampleapp .

> scala version 2.12.2
>
> spark version 1.6.0
>
> sbt version   0.13.13

Any sort of help will be appreciated and would be great if you could provide resources for learning about sbt and spark dependencies .

Please see I am new to scala, spark and sbt .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `library dependencies` line in `build.sbt` seems wrong

correct should be as

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.0"
```

Comment: it worked fine. Can you eleborate what is wrong in it , what are 2.10 and 1.6.0 here and why i need to add these . Please see I am really new to it and it would be great if you could give me some resources for learning about sbt .

Comment: If you visit the [maven dependency repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10/1.6.0) you can see the dependency format under sbt tab. "org.apache.spark" is the groupId, "spark-core_2.10" is artifactId and "1.6.0" is the revision. You can check out [sbt-Reference](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html)